# Помогите пожалуйста не могу сделать выбор горячей клавиши

Tags: c#

Суть в том что я создаю программу "AutoClicker" - это та программа которая симулирует клики через определённое кол-во Минут, секунд (мили-секунд и меньше...), тем самым в программе должна быть сама функция включающую скрипт. Функция такая есть, она работает на F1 - включить скрипт. F2 - выключить скрипт. Но также должна быть смена горячей клавиши, с этим у меня проблемы. Создал текст-бокс, в котором при нажатии клавиши - текст текст-бокса будет меняться на нажатую клавишу. Но мне нужна кнопка "C" - стереть, и кнопка "ОК" - принять. Надо чтоб при нажатии на кнопку "ОК" горячая клавиша менялась на выбранную клавишу. Вот изображения: [image: как писать переменную дефолтной клавиши, которая ещё будет заменяться?][image: сам код нажатия старта скрипта и выключения скрипта.]
На первом изображении я хочу у вас спросить - какой тип переменной нужен для дефолтного значение - которое будет изменяться с нажатием клавиши "ОК". На втором изображении ничего не требуется, просто показан скрипт того как происходит нажатие.

Comment: Примеры кода лучше присылать в текстовом формате.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял то вам нужно сделать следующее:

```
public Key keystart = Key.F1;
public Key keystop = Key.F2;
```

Не совсем понятно зачем вы используете GetAsyncKeyState, когда есть стандартное событие `KeyDown` и используется это так:

после `InitializeComponent();`
Подписываемся на событие нажатия кнопки `this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;`
Внутри метода и реализуем вашу логику по проверке

```
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key==keystart)
        {
            //Тут запуск скрипта            
        }

        if(e.Key==keystop )
        {
            //Тут остановка скрипта            
        }
    }
```

Теперь для того что бы изменить горячую клавишу, вам нужно всего лишь поменять значение `keystart` или `keystop`

Comment: Я использую GetAsyncKeyState потому что действие нажатие должно совершаться не только в самой программе, но и в игре.